# PHP Foreach glob into two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, glob

I want my array to be two dimensional. My code is :

```
$tabelka=glob('music/*');
$tabelkaa=natsort($tabelka);


foreach ($tabelka as $filename) {


     $list .= '<td>' . filesize($filename) . '</td><td>' . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename)) . '</td>'.PHP_EOL;


     }

    echo ($list);
```

This code is on external device (rapsberry pi) and is used on server with 'file()' command.
To achieve what i want a two dimensional array is needed. One dimension of this array needs to be filesize and the second would be filemtime.

Comment: Make an array instead of adding it to a list variable

Comment: To be honest with you, i have no idea how to put it into an array, i always used variables

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you'd show an excerpt of how the final array should look like. Just saying it should be *two dimensional* is really not enough. How should the outer array be indexed? By number or filename? And what about the inner array keys? `filesize` and `filemtime`, or numerically `0`, `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = array();
foreach($tabelka as $filename) {
   $data[$filename] = array('mtime' => filemtime($filename), 'size' => filesize($filename));
}
```